# Converting a Hex values to date in C#

Tags: binary, hex

dI have a program that has dates stored in binary and displayed on the program as YY/MM/DD format. I use XVI32(http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to look at the binary file in Hexadecimal and got the following results

For example,

Hex value: 31 07 01 00
Date value: 85/06/18 (in YY/MM/DD format)

Another example,

Hex value: EF 1B 01 00
Date value: 00/01/01 (in YY/MM/DD format)

Final example,

Hex value: 32 07 01 00
Date value: 85/06/19 (in YY/MM/DD format)

I don't need the programming code, but need to understand the conversion from hex value to actual readable date format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number is a little-endian representation of the number of days since a certain epoch.  It looks like the software isn't calculate something quite right, because the date is just a few days shy of 1801-01-01.

```
+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+
|    Date    | Hex value  | Decimal (days) | Date - days |
+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1985-06-18 | 0x00010731 | 67377          | 1800-12-28  |
| 1985-06-19 | 0x00010732 | 67378          | 1800-12-28  |
| 2000-01-01 | 0x00011bef | 72687          | 1800-12-28  |
+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

It might be interesting to see what it converts 1801-01-01 into.  If it is using 1800-12-28 as the epoch, it should convert to 4, or `04 00 00 00` when saved to the file.  If it converts to `00 00 00 00` then the date math used by the software is skipping over some dates somewhere.

So, in summary: The hex value represents the number of days since the possible epoch of 1800-12-28.  To get the date, the number of days is added to this date, which results in the date displayed in the program.